# What is the best way of finding library conflicts in a large application?

Tags: linux, shared-library, dynamic-linking, strace, dynamic-loading

I have a large application (let's call it P) with lots of dependencies to boost, Qt, zlib, libpng, etc. Recently, I have added a feature to P that needs to dynamically load a new shared object (let's call it `lib1.so`). `lib1.so` is dependent to MATLAB api. As a result, it will be dependent to lots of libraries that  P already is dependent to.

The problem is that when I try to dynamically load `lib1.so` inside P (using the QLibrary class of Qt 5.12), the loading is failed. The failure message is that a Matlab shared object cannot be found. But the shared object is already there and its path is inside LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

If I try to load `lib1.so` inside a simple application (with the same LD_LIBRARY_PATH value) it works fine.

My guess is that P is loading a shared object at load time and `lib1.so` want to load the same library (but a different version) while dynamic loading time and this conflict does not allow `lib1.so` to be loaded inside P.

I have tried to use `strace` command on P, but because `lib1.so` is loaded dynamically, it does not help me a lot.

What is the best way to find this common library that makes this error?

Comment: 1) DLLs are windows.  Shared Objects are linux.  2) have you tried `ldd`?  It will tell you what an .so or executable depends on.

Comment: There are some options to `dlopen()` that may allow you to load otherwise conflicting shared objects.

Comment: @DavidG. I fixed the issue regarding Dlls and shared objects. Thanks. Regarding the dlopen, I am using QLibrary and do not see such kind of options.